# How can I label my left and right ear buds?

Tags: plastics, cables, labeling

My ear buds come labeled left and right, but the writing on them is so small I can't read it without a magnifying glass.  The ear buds are made of a very hard, shiny, black plastic that resists being painted on.  They are also so small that I wouldn't be able to stick a label on them without it bothering my ears.  Also, they are so slick that most labels I have wouldn't stick any way.

I've tried labeling the small cord attached to the buds, but nothing has been able to stay on.

Is there a way to easily label my ear buds so I can quickly tell which is left and right?

Answer (score 0):

You really only need to label ONE of them, and then remember whether that's the left one or the right one.  Since they're black, you could try marking it with either correction fluid (like Wite-Out or Liquid Paper), or a SILVER permanent pen.

Note that you'll probably need to reapply this every few weeks, as it will rub off if you handle them a lot.